# List all privileges of a user

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-services, privileges

I have a windows service which I want to log on to it with a specific user - therefore I added user rights to log on as a service via `ntrights`.

In order to put that into effect - reboot is needed.

To avoid an unnecessary reboot - I would like to check if this user has this privilege already. 

Is there a way to check it?

This is how I add the user rights:

```
 ntrights +r SeServiceLogonRight -u "USER" -m \\%COMPUTERNAME%
```

Comment: You don't need to reboot, the change will take place immediately.

Comment: When I run the command, and check in 'Local Security Policy -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment -> Log on as a service' - I don't see it unless I reboot

Comment: I just have to close and reopen the Local Security Policy console.  At any rate, the change should take effect immediately even if it doesn't show up in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I also wrote an open source tool that might be helpful:

https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/PrivMan

The replacement for this command:

```
ntrights +r SeServiceLogonRight -u "USER" -m \\%COMPUTERNAME%
```

Is this:

```
PrivMan -a "USER" -g "SeServiceLogonRight" -c %COMPUTERNAME%
```

To test whether `USER` has `SeServiceLogonRight` on the computer, you would use this:

```
PrivMan -a "USER" -t "SeServiceLogonRight" -c %COMPUTERNAME%
```

In this case, the exit code (for cmd.exe, this is `%ERRORLEVEL%`, or for PowerShell, `$LASTEXITCODE`) is 1 if the user has the named privileges/rights, or 0 if the user doesn't. Other exit codes indicate an error.

Answer (score -1):

Use this command to check if user has a particular privilege:

```
whoami /priv /fo CSV | convertFrom-Csv | Select-String -Pattern   "SeServiceLogonRight" -Quiet
```

If this command returns `True` then user has the given privilege, else not.

Comment: This won't work, because only privileges, not rights, are included in the user's token.